# Monaco Editor: How do I get the error message to pop out instead of displaying inside the editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

When I run this Hello World! code sample (https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-editor-hello-world)-

```
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
    language: 'javascript'
});
```

and change "function" to say "functionn", I get a suggestion box with a "View the Problem" link. When I click it, it renders the error inside a box within the editor like so-

[image]

Is it possible to render the error in a popout, instead of inside the editor (for scenarios where the editor size is small)?